# Pointer within a vector of structures giving segmentation error

Tags: c

Structure

```
struct products{
    int id;
    char* name;
    int buy;
    int sell;
    int q;
};
```

Within my main I've delcared a vector of `products` and have a for loop to assign the pointer `name` a value as such

```
int main(){
    struct products arr[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%s", arr[i].name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Seems to work fine on the first iteration but when it moves onto the second one that's where it gives me a segmentation error. The only thing I could find on other resources for similar problems was that I could be incorrectly allocating them.

Comment: You haven't assigned the name element to point anywhere.  You are invoking undefined behaviour.  If you code in C, you have to take excruciating care to make sure you are managing your memory correctly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! - Do you know where I could start looking to learn how to best manage my memory? I'm a bit new to C

Comment: From what I understood when I use "scanf("%s", pointer)", that pointer will later be referencing to something that no longer exists and this is why it's giving a segmentation error

Comment: You get the Segfault because the `name` member is uninitialized, meaning that the address that it holds could be anything (likely outside the range of memory accessible by your program). When you `scanf()` and attempt to write to the memory you do not have valid access to, the program Segfaults. If you always answer the question "To what valid memory does my pointer point?" before attempting to write to it, you will never have any problems.

Comment: If you don't want to allocate memory dynamically, why not `#define MAXNAME 64` up top and then define your struct with `char name[MAXNAME];` (adjust `MAXNAME` as desired). Now each `name` member will point to an array of `MAXNAME` characters (able to hold a `63` character string + the `'\0'` nul-terminating character) Then `scanf("%63s", arr[i].name);` to ensure you protect your array bounds. (or use `fgets()` instead)

Comment: Thank you! - I'll definitely keep this in mind to improve and work on implementing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf %s` expects a pointer to space to which it can write a string.

`arr[i].name` was never initialized. It's junk. It's not a (valid) pointer. You need to initialize `arr[i].name` so that it points to space to which `scanf` can write a string.